# How to authenticate in microsoft teams tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

i am creating a asp.net core site, the site is finished and the authentication is made with Azure AD.. The way i made authentication was by following microsoft documentation, registering an app in azure, getting the client Id, etc etc...
It works fine in browser, but when i try to go in my microsoft teams tab, it simply does not even load anything..
I also heard that i could do SSO authentication, i tried, but if i do that then my authentication in the browser doesnt work ! I want to have both browser and teams app authenticating!
I dont know if i am giving enought information or if i am not being clear enough, so ask anything or suggest me to change the question...
Any help on this is appreciated!! Thanks :)

Update:

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
var authTokenRequest = {
    successCallback: function (result) {
        var token = jwtDecode(result);
        document.getElementById("userAqui").innerHTML = "Welcome " + token.payload.name;
    },
    failureCallback: function (error) {
        //window.location.href = "Home/Index";
        //alert('Invalid user! Error:' + error); 
    }
};
microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken(authTokenRequest);
```

im using something like that to get the token, and i receive that token.. but if i do that way, when i open app in the browser without going in teams, i am not getting that token...
what i kinda wanted was something that worked in both ways...

right now for the authentication to work in browser i place this in my json:

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "TenantId": "***",
    "ClientSecret": "***",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

and i have the authentication part in start up it will authenticate ( i have my azure ad App registered in azure)...

can you point me a sample code, where it works on both teams and browser for .net core? something that i could get a guide from :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your own authentication is initiated from script, you can do a check for the `microsoftTeams` object, and based on whether it is present, initiate your own authentication (I presume ADAL or MSAL), or initiate the Teams SSO authentication. Please note that the SSO authentication does not enable you to, for example, call the Graph (you haven't said why you need to authenticate exactly), so if you need to do that, you need to provide admin consent or implement a backend to convert your token to an on-behalf-of token (the [SSO documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#apps-that-require-additional-microsoft-graph-scopes) covers this).

Update: there is an MSAL 2.0 sample that shows how to deal with both Teams AND normal web authentication in the same app (e.g. Teams Tab and also standalone Web page). See [here](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-aad-msal2).

As an example what I mean about checking for `microsoftTeams`, your code could look loosely something like this:

```
    if (microsoftTeams) {
        startTeamsSSO();
    } else {
       startStandaloneWebAuth();
    }
```

Comment: I followed microsoft documentation, and SSO i basic created a javascript function.. I receive the token but if i do that, i cant authenticate in browser anymore :/ im pretty much confused with all this, i am new to this authentication stuff :p

Comment: what do you mean about can't authenticate in browser? Do you mean that you can't use your web app "standalone"? If so, I'll update my answer

Comment: i updated my question, i hope it is a litle more clear :/ i dont even know how to make the question to be honest because i am really lost in this... :/

Comment: ok I see the updates, that's great. Maybe start this from another direction - *why* are you wanting to authenticate the user? For instance, in the Teams example, all you're doing is showing the name - you don't need to authenticate at all for that, you can just use the teams "Context" object to get that. By the way, is this an internal app (e.g. something for inside your company), or external (e.g. something people will use from the App store)?

Comment: I need authentication so that only people inside the org can actually have acess to the application... 
After authentication, i want to only a few people can acess a few actions, like create or edit for example... so the authentication is required for a lot of things :/

Also ( maybe this has nothing to do with it but i kinda think it does) , i need to get all azure AD users in a dropdown, with the permission 
User.ReadBasic.All that i gave in the azure registered app... (i am completly lost in this and lost about 14 hours reading and reading and i feel like i am always in the same page)

Comment: ok, that makes more sense. Did you consider the update I put in my answer above (basically an "if" for microsoftTeams)? Essentially, everything in your first code sample would go inside that

Comment: By the way, another possible route is to use the Microsoft Graph Toolkit - I think it might provide a way to use Teams auth if inside there, and to fall back to MSAL if outside of Teams, but I haven't tested it for that

Comment: This is a great read, by the way: https://bob1german.com/2020/08/31/calling-microsoft-graph-from-your-teams-application-part2/

Comment: where are those functions coming ? startTeamsSSO() or startStandaloneWebAuth() ?

Comment: I just made them up, as an example. In your case, all the code you posted in your first sample would be what would go inside `startTeamsSSO`

Comment: I was thinking about that but i had no sure, even though i do that if statement and if i place what i have inside a function called startTeamsSSO, i have no idea how to create a function for startStandaloneWebAuth();...

As i told you, that was made by following documentation, only registered the app in azure , updated app.settings and then i said i configured authentication in startup...
I have no idea how to create a function that will contain that or that would stop that from being done.. :(

Comment: ok I understand now - I thought you were doing something like calling 'acquireTokenRedirect' or 'acquireTokenPopup' on MSAL, for example. Did you start with a sample app of some sort? The authentication mechanism must be inside there somewhere...

Comment: https://ypcode.io/posts/2020/07/use-csom-aspnetcore/

I used that tutorial for making another part of the app, but the start is the authentication part that i followed for the first time!  My startup code is more or less like that (i changed the scopes), my app.settings is just like that but with my information... 
I dont know if it actually there are more stuff going on behind but i dont think so... (that tutorial is for me to get to sharepoint through azure, so i had to authenticate to azure and all that is explained here), i did not start with a sample app :/

Comment: So I haven't looked into it in much detail, but the app is basically wrapping the auth code in internal libraries (Microsoft.Identity.Web). I'm no expert on AAD / web security, but I think you'll need to rather implement the MSAL library your code directly, in order to achieve what you're trying to do. See here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview .

Comment: Thanks for the help, that seems a little complicated to do, anyways
I will mark it as solution to help anyone that is in the same situation than me.

Comment: ok thanks. Sorry it's not more straightforward. Perhaps another idea - create two "entry points" for your app - one for when it's hosted in Teams, and one for standalone. Like basically two slightly different Razor shared views, for instance